# Need to find the melody for Eicha

Tags: tisha-bav, trop-cantillation, lamentations-eicha

Our Rabbi is on vacation and I have been volunteered to read Eicha for Tisha b'Av.

I would like to use a correct melody.  (I can follow trop pretty well and lain Torah with some preparation, so if the melody consists of defining each trop phrase's tune, I can handle that.)

Can anybody point me to any traditional melody, on the web since I have run out of time?  Thanks

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/953164/jewish/The-Reading-of-Megilat-Eichah.htm

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your post to make it [less personal](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1788/9682)?

Comment: @DonielF In this context, I think it's fine as is. It's not a *psak halacha* question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFkwvVHtyMM&index=4&list=PLPP_mgx1E4CFvTTV1Z-JL3ffokFRwjKlS) by Moshe Weisblum. He is how I learned how to lein the megillot.

You may also want to try Pocket Torah Trope. It is a very helpful app which will teach you the trope for eichah, however doesn't have the actual megillah.

I hope this is helpful

Comment: "however doesn't have the actual megillah" - what does this mean? Is "Pocket Torah Trope" a smart phone app?

Comment: @DanF It is a smart phone app which teaches you the trope for the megillah, however does not have a recording of the actual megillah being leined

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if I can look at it. It will probably come in useful for me when Mas'ei comes.

Comment: @DanF Its sister app, Pocket Torah, has the leining  for all the parshiyot, not just the trope

Answer (score 1):

[Page 1 - etnachta/sof pasuk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEbra.jpg)[image: Page 2/3 - katon/tevir/revii][image: Page 4/5 - telisha/geresh/segol][image: sof perek]

A. W. Binder's Ashkenazi system according to "Biblical Chant" (1959)

Comment: There's a separate niggun for chapter 3, which I would recommend looking up a recording for, since it's  unrelated to any of the other chapters for the te'amim. Don't use Chabad for that, because they don't use the niggun.  but you should definitely find it, because without it Chapter 3 goes on forever

Comment: Is how long it lasts really the determining factor in what the appropriate tradition is?

Answer (score 0):

[Virtual Cantor](http://www.virtualcantor.com/tbav.htm) and and [Chabad](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/953164/jewish/The-Reading-of-Megilat-Eichah.htm) have recordings for the reading of Megillat Eichah according to the general Ashkenazi nusach.